# Getting unknown host exception in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, unknown-host

I have been testing HTTP request for the URL: [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and getting unknown host error in `jmeter`.

[image: HTTP REQUEST PAGE[![][1]]

Comment: What is your exact HTTP request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that JMeter cannot resolve the IP address of `google.com` website. Most probably this is due to your network settings, i.e. your machine uses a corporate [proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server) in order to access the Internet.

Contact your network administrator in order to obtain the required proxy settings (hostname, port, username and password) and [configure JMeter to use the proxy server to access external resources](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server), i.e. launch it as:

```
jmeter -H your_proxy_host -P your_proxy_port -u your_proxy_username -a your_proxy_password
```

---

Apart from the above:

1. Don't load test public resources without explicit permission of their owner as your actions might be considered as [DoS attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) and your IP address might become blacklisted. So use something from your [Intranet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intranet) instead of Google, this way you will kill 2 birds with one stone:

   - you will not need to configure proxy
   - your actions will be clear from the law perspective

   if you don't have anything you can test in your Intranet you can consider using special websites like [blazedemo.com](http://blazedemo.com/) or [newtours.demoaut.com](http://www.newtours.demoaut.com/)
2. According to [JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest available JMeter version](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5) (or whatever is the current version available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page)

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to make such mistakes when you congfigurate HTTP Request in the JMeter UI.

Suppose now you want to test this URL: `https://www.your_host.com/your_path/`, you should split this URL into different parts and put them into corresponding JMeter's fields repectively.

- Protocol[http]: https (red marker)
- Server Name or IP: www.your_host.com (blue marker)
- Path: /your_path (yellow marker)

NOTE: DONT put your complete URL in the "Server Name or IP". 
[image]